# How to save lisp interaction history for future re-load?

Tags: common-lisp, slime

I am using [portacle](https://portacle.github.io/) as my Common Lisp environment. When I save my file it saves the entire REPL including the `CL-USER>`. This results in compilation error when I try to load the file.

I want to save the code and resume from where I left off. I have been writing code at REPL, saving the work in file from the buffer by using key-chords <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd>. But this is breaking the continuity of the project. Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Edit the code a file like in any other language and use `C-c C-c` to compile the current toplevel form or `C-c C-k` to compile and load the whole file. The REPL is more for small experiments, running tests, using dev tools (profilers, inspectors, etc.), etc.

Comment: I tried C-c C-k chord at the mini buffer but it says undefined. Do I have to load the file through (load pathname.lisp) then use C-c C-c/ C-c C-k to compile.

Comment: Is the file using lisp mode? Portacle might also define different keys for them. Try using `M-x describe-function` to see what the keybindings are for the [compilation commands](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Compilation.html#Compilation) listed in the SLIME manual.

Comment: what is undefined ? You open a .lisp file and `C-c C-k` in there (no mini buffer involved). Also, hope this helps: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/getting-started.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are using REPL in a terminal, you might find
[`dribble`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_dribbl.htm) useful.

However, if you are running in Emacs, you should almost never type
anything at the prompt yourself.
You edit a Lisp file in Lisp mode and send your code to the Lisp REPL
using [<kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> or <kbd>C-M-x</kbd>](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/External-Lisp.html) &c.

You should also consider using [SLIME](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) which also comes with your [Portacle](https://portacle.github.io/).

Comment: I'll add [eval-in-repl](https://github.com/kaz-yos/eval-in-repl) with its `M-x eir-slime` function, handy when I want to use the output of the command (not available in the REPL after C-x C-e).

Answer (score -1):

In portacle:

1. make sure that the REPL-window is the active one
2. click: File -> save as, enter "repl.log" as name

with any editor:

3. make a copy named xyz.lisp of repl.log
4. edit xyz.lisp, removing everything not a function-  or variable definition.

in restarted portacle:

5. switch with (ctrl-X O) to the scratch-buffer
6. load xyz.lisp  (ctrl-X ctrl-F), to a buffer
7. with (ctrl-C ctrl-K) compile and load it to the
   REPL-buffer.